# I'm only able to access values in the outer JSON array , is there a way of accessing the values of the inner JSON array in Oracle plsql?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

```json
[
  {
    "name": "sometablename",
    "numofcolumns": 5,
    "numofrows": 5,
    "colheadings": [
      {
        "colname": "customcol1",
        "coltype": "number"
      },
      {
        "colname": "customcol2",
        "coltype": "varchar2"
      },
      {
        "colname": "customcol3",
        "coltype": "varchar2"
      },
      {
        "colname": "customcol4",
        "coltype": "varchar2"
      },
      {
        "colname": "customcol5",
        "coltype": "number"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Which value you want to extract. How your end result should look alike.

Comment: ... and which method are you using, and what's the version of your currently used database?

Comment: PL/SQL was first introduced in Oracle Database 6, so I am curious to see your "PL/SQL" that is being executed against your Oracle Database 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you will want to correct is that your JSON is invalid. There is an extra comma after the closing bracket of your `colheadings` array.

If you are using SQL, you can get the values of the inner JSON array just by specifying the path.

```sql
WITH
    sample_json
    AS
        (SELECT '[{ "name": "sometablename", "numofcolumns": 5, "numofrows": 5, "colheadings": [{ "colname": "customcol1", "coltype": "number" }, { "colname": "customcol2", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol3", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol4", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol5", "coltype": "number" } ], }]'    AS json_text
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT json_value (s.json_text, '$[0].name')                       AS outer_name,
       json_value (s.json_text, '$[0].colheadings[0].colname')     AS colname1,
       json_value (s.json_text, '$[0].colheadings[0].coltype')     AS coltype1,
       json_value (s.json_text, '$[0].colheadings[1].colname')     AS colname2,
       json_value (s.json_text, '$[0].colheadings[1].coltype')     AS coltype2
  FROM sample_json s;
```

If you are using PL/SQL, you will need to continually get the nested objects/arrays until you are at the level that contains the information you are trying to retrieve. See the example below (after correcting the invalid JSON):

```sql
DECLARE
    l_outer_array        json_array_t
        := json_array_t (
               '[{ "name": "sometablename", "numofcolumns": 5, "numofrows": 5, "colheadings": [{ "colname": "customcol1", "coltype": "number" }, { "colname": "customcol2", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol3", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol4", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol5", "coltype": "number" } ] }]');
    l_outer_object       json_object_t := TREAT (l_outer_array.get (0) AS json_object_t);
    l_col_headings       json_array_t := l_outer_object.get_array ('colheadings');
    l_col_heading_info   json_object_t;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0 .. l_col_headings.get_size - 1
    LOOP
        l_col_heading_info := TREAT (l_col_headings.get (i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Column ' || (i + 1));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('---colname : ' || l_col_heading_info.get_string ('colname'));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('---coltype : ' || l_col_heading_info.get_string ('coltype'));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

### Update

To use APEX_JSON, you will need to specify the full path of the key that want to get the data for. Below is an example of how to loop through all the "colheading" objects. The `get_count` function returns the number of items in the array so it knows how many times to loop.

```sql
DECLARE
    j   apex_json.t_values;
BEGIN
    apex_json.parse (
        p_values   => j,
        p_source   =>
            '[{ "name": "sometablename", "numofcolumns": 5, "numofrows": 5, "colheadings": [{ "colname": "customcol1", "coltype": "number" }, { "colname": "customcol2", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol3", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol4", "coltype": "varchar2" }, { "colname": "customcol5", "coltype": "number" } ] }]');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 (p_path => '[%d].name', p_values => j, p0 => 1));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (apex_json.get_count (p_path => '[%d].colheadings', p_values => j, p0 => 1));

    FOR i IN 1 .. apex_json.get_count (p_path => '[%d].colheadings', p_values => j, p0 => 1)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put (apex_json.get_varchar2 (p_path     => '[%d].colheadings[%d].colname',
                                                 p_values   => j,
                                                 p0         => 1,
                                                 p1         => i));

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   '---'
                              || apex_json.get_varchar2 (p_path     => '[%d].colheadings[%d].coltype',
                                                         p_values   => j,
                                                         p0         => 1,
                                                         p1         => i));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

#### Output

```
sometablename
5
customcol1---number
customcol2---varchar2
customcol3---varchar2
customcol4---varchar2
customcol5---number
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle version 5.1 and sql developer version 11g, I'm getting errors for the above code:  Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_ARRAY_T' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_OBJECT_T' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_ARRAY_T' must be declared

Comment: `JSON_OBJECT_T` and `JSON_ARRAY_T` are available in Oracle Database 12.2. If you're using that old of a database, it should really be mentioned in the question. Please edit the question to show how you are currently getting the values of the outer JSON array.

Comment: I can access the outer JSON array like this: apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path=>[%d].name, p_values=>j, p0=>1)

Comment: j := the json array

Comment: What version of APEX are you using? As far as I'm aware, any version of APEX that has the  APEX_JSON package, does not support Oracle Database 5.1

Comment: This is the version of Oracle Database I'm using: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                      

Sorry about the confusion, I mixed up the Apex version with the oracle version.
the Apex version is 5.1.0.00.45

Comment: I have added an update that shows how to get the values using APEX_JSON